# Isotope filter - have to click twice to filter

Tags: javascript, fancybox, jquery-isotope

I am using an Isotope filter combined with a Fancybox gallery and have modified the Isotope JS so that Fancybox only scrolls through those images that are filtered. The problem is that now to activate the Isotope filter I have to click twice on the filter menu to initialise it. I'm hoping someone may be able to spot the problem in my code to help me out:

Here is the JS for the filter:

```
DK.filter = function (){
if($('#projects').length > 0){      
    var $container = $('#projects');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.isotope({
          // options
          animationEngine: 'best-available',
          itemSelector : '.item-thumbs',
          layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });
    });


    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

      $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');


    // open filtered items only

  $('#filters a').click(function(){
          var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $('#projects').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
        if(selector == "*"){
         $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
        } else{ 
         $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });



        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function'         ) {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope( options );
        }

        return false;
    });
}
}
```

and here is the HTML from the beginning of the filtered section:

```
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <!-- Filter -->
            <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
                <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li class="type-work">Type of Work</li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".red">Red</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".green">Green</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".blue">Blue</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Filter -->
        </div>

        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row">
                <section id="projects">
                    <ul id="thumbs">

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name --><!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                      <li class="item-thumbs span3 red">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Office" href="_include/img/work/full/red-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-search"></span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/red.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->
```

A development page is also located here: [development page](http://www.davidkneale.com/filter/)
I've been trying to sort this for days... but am a total novice so not having any success. Any help greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: generally speaking it's not a good idea to modify original plugin's js files unless you know what you are doing ... custom modification normally tend to lack of support

Comment: I agree. Should have been more clear that this is in my custom JS file. I didn't modify the original plugin's js file... pretty early in the AM where I am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was binding to the click event twice and returning false in the end of the code, so I was breaking other binds from initialising. To prevent the browser's default behavior it's better to use event `.preventDefault()`. [Here's the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ5NN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this for a friend yesterday. You need to bind isotope once to the whole container AND then to individual filter, so add an initialization line before the click handlers for filter anchors:

```
// bind to container
$('#projects').isotope();
// then add filters
$('#filters a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $('#projects').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
        if(selector == "*"){
         $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
        } else{ 
         $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Hi Lim. Thanks so much for your response... apologies for my lack of understanding but I've modified the custom JS as you've indicated above with no change. Are any other changes required for my custom JS other than this one and did I also need to make a change in the HTML? Thanks so much.

Comment: Is it possible for you to setup a jsfiddle for this problem?

Comment: I'm working with a bootstrap template that has all manner of attached CSS and JS files and I'm having trouble getting the jsfilddle to work correctly. There's a link to a page I'm using to try to resolve the issue in my original post if that is any help.

Comment: @ Lim H : I managed to get a jsfiddle sorted: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ5NN/
Any help on this much appreciated!

Comment: Apologies for bumping this topic but I still don't have a fix on this. If someone could look at my jsfiddle.net/DZ5NN and offer any solutions I'd appreciate it!